# My python game won't output what I want

Tags: python, loops, printing, while-loop, function

The output generates the print answer for both yes and no responses. I would like it to generate
one answer for yes and one answer for no, as inputed by the user.

```
import time
import random
time.sleep(0)
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Welcome to the zombie apocalypse simulator!")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print()
time.sleep(0)


print("You wake up in the backseat of an old 1995 suburu, shirtless and confused.") 
time.sleep(0)
print("Looking out the dusty window, you can make out the skyline of a distant")
print("forgotten metropolis.")
print()
time.sleep(0)

def ask(question):
    answer = input(question + " {y/n}")
    return answer in ['Yes','YES','y', 'Y','yes', 'n', 'N', 'no', 'NO', 'No']

while ask("You see a backpack in the from seat of the car. Do you take it?"):
    if ['Yes','YES','y', 'Y','yes']:
        print("You look inside only to find a brown hoodie, a utility knife, a can of tuna")
        print("and a half full water bottle.") 
    if ['n', 'N', 'no', 'NO', 'No']: 
        print("You leave the bag behind.")
    break
```

Comment: Hint: A list is always True, unless it's the empty list `[]`. So `if ['Yes','YES','y', 'Y','yes']` will always be True. You need to fix up your `ask()` function because `in` doesn't work like you appear to think it does. PS. Please fix up the indenting of your code.

Comment: Note that indentation really, really matters in Python.  Please present the code in a format that could be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If `answer = 'YES'` then 
`return answer in ['Yes', .. , 'No']` returns `True` otherwise `False`. Basically, `in` will tell you whether the list contains the given element or not. So, in your `ask` function, if an user enters one of the possible answers a `True` value is returned which makes the next while loop behave like

```
# ask question, if answer is positive
while True:
    # check if yes, do something
    # else do something.
    break
```

There is no place inside the code where you are actually checking if the answer is yes or no. So, to output accordingly ensure that you check for these values. (Look at the hint in question's comment)